# I'd like to use iframe to videos and contents posted other sites?will I be violating any law

Tags: seo, blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading another domain's content in a modal iframe - acceptable?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28367/loading-another-domains-content-in-a-modal-iframe-acceptable)

My url is www.indiaracetips.com and if I use iframe in my site will any one sue me?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the tags you chose. Is this more a legal or a seo question?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: quite possibly. Depends on the content and its provenance. Your question is a little vague, therefore difficult to accurately answer.

Here's a simple checklist:

- Do you own or are you the author of the content loaded in the iframe?

  - If you don't, do you have the original author/content creator's permission to use it?

    - If you don't, the answer is that you may get sued or issued a takedown notice.

Basically, if you don't own the content or have permission to use the content, don't use it. This doesn't seem to pertain to SEO though--unless you count a takedown notice as a negative hit.

Comment: neither I own the content nor I have the permission.My thought was any how the page is loaded at their site only and may be the visitors are ignorant of the fact.As regards the tags sorry I shall use the appropriate one henceforth